# Discord.js web page not logging in

Tags: javascript, html, discord.js

I've got a personal discord.js bot that's able to work and function properly locally and on my raspberry pi for deployment. However I'm trying to figure out a way to work in a web page to allow administrators access to run functions without needing to type commands in through the discord client. I started with a bare bones basic web page with just a single button and a script to log in and send a message to a channel. However when attempting to send the message I just get the error "TypeError: client.channels.get is not a function". I've determined that I'm just getting this error because the bot isn't actually logging in but can't seem to figure out exactly why it's not logging in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="discord.12.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    
    function test() {
        try {
            const client = new Discord.Client();
            client.login('token');  // api token
            let channel = client.channels.get(channelid); //undeclared channel id
            channel.send("This is a test");
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Message sent";
        } catch (error) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = error;
        }
    }
    
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="test">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Test</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I've also moved the the client declaration and login outside of the test() function with no different results.

Edit2: Realized that I've got 12.5.1 loaded in this script instead of 11.6.3 that I've been using elsewhere. I've attempted using the newer: client.cache.channels.get(channelid);
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

As well as a fetch>then>catch I was not able to see the error in browser unfortunately but it did not send the message.

Comment: Hey, just a heads up. You do not want to post your API tokens publicly. You should probably generate a new token for your discord bot immediately.

Comment: It's not tied to any server currently, already changed it. Thanks for keeping an eye out though!

Comment: could it be that `.get` is not the correct method? what if you try [`.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch)?

Comment: client.channels.get is the exact same method used in the standalone version of the bot. Doesn't listen on client.on("message" either, indicating that it's not actually logged on. Doesn't show logged in on user panel on discord either.

Comment: could have something to do with [this](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/2078#issuecomment-697829305)?

Comment: Potentially, I'll have to see if there's a way that I can put a listening port on the bot to accept incoming data instead of trying to incorporate a portion of the bot on the webpage

Comment: Did you define `Discord`?

Answer (score 0):

So I went ahead and just changed from v12 and dropped down to 11.6.4 after reverting changes from attempting other fixes and I was able to get it resolved. Not ideal but will do for what I need it to do.